# Они проходили между деревьями и пели "Отговорила роща золотая..."(.)

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

**Они проходили между деревьями и пели "Отговорила роща золотая..."(.)**

- В таком предложении, которое кончается текстом в кавычках (чья-то реплика, название песни, цитата), нужна ли точка в конце, если перед кавычкой стоят знаки "многоточие", "вопросительный знак", "восклицательный знак"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Отговорила роща золотая..." — это и название стихотворения С. Есенина, и первые его строчки, а также и название романса. Я вижу здесь два варианта.

1. Прямая речь. Точка после кавычек в конце предложения не ставится, т. к. прямая речь (слова романса) заканчивается многоточием. (Они конкретно **пели**.)
   **Они проходили между деревьями и пели: "Отговорила роща золотая..."**
2. Если цитата [название нашего стихотворения или песни] не является самостоятельным предложением и заканчивается многоточием, то после закрывающих кавычек ставится точка, относящаяся ко всему предложению в целом. (Они пели романс с таким-то **названием**, и это название входит в состав предложения.)
   **Они проходили между деревьями и пели "Отговорила роща золотая...".**

[Знаки препинания при цитатах](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/53.htm)

Итак, точка ставится, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, восклицательный или вопросительный знак, но название или цитата не являются самостоятельными предложениями (т. е. выступают как члены того предложения, в которое включены).
Мне посоветовали прочитать **"А поутру они проснулись…".**
К следующему уроку необходимо выучить **"Нате!".**
Забыла отдать в библиотеку **"Как нам обустроить Россию?".**

Answer (score 3):

Если цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, не является самостоятельным предложением, то после нее ставится точка:

М. В. Ломоносов писал, что «красота, великолепие, сила и богатство российского языка явствует довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных…».

Если же цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, является самостоятельным предложением, то после кавычек точка не ставится (как при прямой речи): В. Г. Белинский писал: «В “Онегине” все части органически сочленены…»

1. перед закрывающей кавычкой ставятся знаки вопросительный, восклицательный и многоточие, если они относятся к словам, заключенным в кавычки:

**«Как ни грустно в этом непонятном мире, но он всё же прекрасен!» – эти слова И. Бунина К. Паустовский предпослал одному из своих сочинений; Когда Багрицкий читал пушкинское «Для берегов отчизны дольной…», его нельзя было слушать без волнения ;** если же эти знаки относятся ко всему предложению с включенными в него закавыченными словами, то ставятся в конце предложения, в том числе после закрывающей кавычки: **Пришвин однажды написал о себе (в частном письме), что он «поэт, распятый на кресте прозы»!**

3) если перед закрывающей кавычкой стоит знак вопросительный, восклицательный или многоточие (и на этом предложение заканчивается), то те же знаки, необходимые по условиям всего предложения, не повторяются после закрывающей кавычки; неодинаковые знаки (перед кавычкой и после кавычки) ставятся; **ср.: «Вы читали романы «Что делать?» и «Кто виноват ?»; Кто не знает великолепных слов А. Блока: «Сотри случайные черты. И ты увидишь — мир прекрасен...»?; Неужели вы не прочитали роман «Что делать?»!**

Розенталь, Лопатин.